# Why does edittext have limit?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tryed to make code editor with Edittext.
However, when I loaded huge code with edittext, the code was automatically cut.
It seemed there's a limit of text size in edittext.(I didn't set any max length to edittext)

So, I decided to make custom view(code editor) that can handle large text. But I still don't know why edittext can't handle large text.

Why does edittext have limit???

Comment: There is no default max length on a EditText.  You're mistaken.  You can put a max on with an input filter, but you'd have to choose to do so.  That said, for any non-trivial editor you wouldn't want just an edit text anyway.  It would be unlikely to have the kind of features you'd need for a code editor, especially with things like syntax hilighting, line numbering, etc

Comment: @GabeSechan But when i pasted huge text in a edittext, the text was cut and I couldn't write more.

Comment: Did you allow it to extend to more than one line? Maybe it's being cut off by the edge of your layout? EditTexts don't scroll.

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes I allowed that... And I also put edittext in scrollview and scroll worked well.

Comment: Is your String possibly more than 2147483647 characters?

Comment: Also, there are a few libraries that already do what you want, such as https://github.com/0xFireball/Enlightened. No point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @TheWanderer Oh, that make sense. I'll check that.